# grunt command does not run server while configuring EaselJS project

Tags: javascript, configuration, gruntjs, easeljs

I am experiencing some problems while configuring my project for game development in EaselJS. Below you can see my `Grunt.js` file.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    browserify: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'build/scripts/app.bundle.js': ['app/lib/main.js']
            }
        }
    },
    copy: {
        scripts: {
            src: [
                'bower_components/easeljs/lib/easeljs-0.8.0.combined.js',
            ],
            dest: 'build/scripts/',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true
        },
        html: {
            src: [
                'app/index.html',
            ],
            dest: 'build/',
            expand: true,
            flatten: true
        }
    },
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                base: 'build'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true
        },
        scripts: {
            files: ['app/lib/**/*.js', 'app/*.html'],
            tasks: ['build']
        }
    }
});

// Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('build', ['browserify', 'copy']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['build', 'connect', 'watch']);};
```

Whenever I run the grunt command on the command line, Windows asks 'How to open this file?'. When I choose my browser it just opens and show me the Grunt.js file.

I would be really thankful if you would help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I had named my file `Grunt.js` instead of `Gruntfile.js`.
I changed it to `Gruntfile.js`, ran the grunt command and it was working as expected.